# How to use MAX() in Join query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a query that gets a RECID from the RECIPT table, it's custname from the Customer table and the max of RECID on the  RECIPT. But somehow this query throws an error. It started when I added max(MAX(REC.REC_Id_I) As RECID).

Query is:

```
SELECT
    REC.REC_Id_I,
    REC.REC_No_V,
    CUS.CUS_Name_V,
    REC.REC_PaidAmount_M,
    CASE
        WHEN REC.REC_PayMode_C = 'C' THEN 'Cash'
        ELSE 'Cheque'
    END AS REC_PayMode_C,
    REC.REC_BankName_V,
    REC.REC_BankAddress,
    REC.REC_ChequeNo_V,
    convert(varchar, REC.REC_ChequeDate_D, 103) AS REC_ChequeDate_D,
    REC.REC_Date_D,
    MAX(REC.REC_Id_I) As RECID
FROM TBL_Receipts REC
JOIN TBL_CustomerMaster CUS ON REC.REC_CustomerId_I = CUS.CUS_Id_I
WHERE
  REC_Active_c='y'
  AND REC_SalesMasterId_I='0'
ORDER BY REC_Id_I
```

Error IS:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_Receipt_Select, Line 15 Column 'TBL_Receipts.REC_Id_I' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: MSSQL is not MySQL. You need to `GROUP BY` your columns explicitly.

Comment: @Juhana The error message indicates it's MSSQL. MySQL would just implicitly `GROUP BY` the columns.

Comment: The same way you use `GROUP BY` everywhere else.

Comment: I use `GROUP BY` even it shows error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still have problems with your GROUP BY clause, you can try something like this, it should work even though it's not an optimal solution

```
SELECT
    REC.REC_Id_I,
    REC.REC_No_V,
    CUS.CUS_Name_V,
    REC.REC_PaidAmount_M,
    CASE
        WHEN REC.REC_PayMode_C = 'C' THEN 'Cash'
        ELSE 'Cheque'
    END AS REC_PayMode_C,
    REC.REC_BankName_V,
    REC.REC_BankAddress,
    REC.REC_ChequeNo_V,
    convert(varchar, REC.REC_ChequeDate_D, 103) AS REC_ChequeDate_D,
    REC.REC_Date_D,
    recid.maxRECID As RECID
FROM TBL_Receipts REC
JOIN TBL_CustomerMaster CUS ON REC.REC_CustomerId_I = CUS.CUS_Id_I
JOIN (SELECT MAX(REC_ID_I) as maxRECID, REC_CustomerId_I FROM REC group by REC_CustomerId_I) as recid ON recid.REC_CustomerId_I = REC.REC_CustomerId_I
WHERE
  REC_Active_c='y'
  AND REC_SalesMasterId_I='0'
ORDER BY REC_Id_I
```

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much need to group by all the selected columns except the aggregate function. If you think about how the results will be displayed it should make sense to you that all the columns should be in the group by:

```
SELECT
    REC.REC_Id_I,
    REC.REC_No_V,
    CUS.CUS_Name_V,
    REC.REC_PaidAmount_M,
    CASE
        WHEN REC.REC_PayMode_C = 'C' THEN 'Cash'
        ELSE 'Cheque'
    END AS REC_PayMode_C,
    REC.REC_BankName_V,
    REC.REC_BankAddress,
    REC.REC_ChequeNo_V,
    convert(varchar, REC.REC_ChequeDate_D, 103) AS REC_ChequeDate_D,
    REC.REC_Date_D,
    MAX(REC.REC_Id_I) As RECID
FROM TBL_Receipts REC
JOIN TBL_CustomerMaster CUS ON REC.REC_CustomerId_I = CUS.CUS_Id_I
WHERE
  REC_Active_c='y'
  AND REC_SalesMasterId_I='0'
 GROUP BY 
    REC.REC_Id_I,
    REC.REC_No_V,
    CUS.CUS_Name_V,
    REC.REC_PaidAmount_M,
    CASE
        WHEN REC.REC_PayMode_C = 'C' THEN 'Cash'
        ELSE 'Cheque'
    END AS REC_PayMode_C,
    REC.REC_BankName_V,
    REC.REC_BankAddress,
    REC.REC_ChequeNo_V,
    convert(varchar, REC.REC_ChequeDate_D, 103) AS REC_ChequeDate_D,
    REC.REC_Date_D
ORDER BY REC_Id_I
```

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting when you add the `GROUP BY` clause? Never write that you get an error, always write what the error is.

I don't know how you wrote your query with `GROUP BY` clause (because you haven't shown it to us), but try this:

```
SELECT
    REC.REC_Id_I,
    REC.REC_No_V,
    CUS.CUS_Name_V,
    REC.REC_PaidAmount_M,
    CASE
        WHEN REC.REC_PayMode_C = 'C' THEN 'Cash'
        ELSE 'Cheque'
    END AS REC_PayMode_C,
    REC.REC_BankName_V,
    REC.REC_BankAddress,
    REC.REC_ChequeNo_V,
    convert(varchar, REC.REC_ChequeDate_D, 103) AS REC_ChequeDate_D,
    REC.REC_Date_D,
    MAX(REC.REC_Id_I) As RECID
FROM TBL_Receipts REC
JOIN TBL_CustomerMaster CUS ON REC.REC_CustomerId_I = CUS.CUS_Id_I
WHERE
  REC_Active_c='y'
  AND REC_SalesMasterId_I='0'
GROUP BY
  REC.REC_Id_I,
  REC.REC_No_V,
  CUS.CUS_Name_V,
  REC.REC_PaidAmount_M,
  CASE
      WHEN REC.REC_PayMode_C = 'C' THEN 'Cash'
      ELSE 'Cheque'
  END,
  REC.REC_BankName_V,
  REC.REC_BankAddress,
  REC.REC_ChequeNo_V,
  convert(varchar, REC.REC_ChequeDate_D, 103),
  REC.REC_Date_D
ORDER BY REC_Id_I;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using select statement i solved my problem

`Code is:`

```
 SELECT 
    REC.REC_Id_I,
    REC.REC_No_V,
    CUS.CUS_Name_V,
    REC.REC_PaidAmount_M,
     CASE WHEN REC.REC_PayMode_C='C' THEN 'Cash' ELSE 'Cheque' END AS REC_PayMode_C,
     REC.REC_BankName_V,
    REC.REC_BankAddress,
    REC.REC_ChequeNo_V,
    convert(varchar, REC.REC_ChequeDate_D, 103) AS REC_ChequeDate_D,
     REC.REC_Date_D,`(SELECT MAX(REC_Id_I) from TBL_Receipts) AS RECID` 
    FROM TBL_Receipts REC  
    JOIN TBL_CustomerMaster CUS 
    on  REC.REC_CustomerId_I=CUS.CUS_Id_I where REC_Active_c='y' and REC_SalesMasterId_I='0'
    ORDER BY REC_Id_I
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate aggregate function and to get the corresponding column values you must have all the other columns in GROUP BY (except the ones on which you are calculating the aggregate).

```
SELECT table_1.column_A,
       MAX(table_2.column_B),
       table_2.column_C

FROM table_1
     INNER JOIN table_2   ON table_1.column_A=table_2.column_B

GROUP BY table_1.column_A,
         table_2.column_C
```